# express-session doesn't find the req.session.user object in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express-session

I am using node js for backend to maintain session I am using express-session, my problem is I am unable to access the req.session.user in other routes, I am debugging inside login route I can see the req.session.user but other routes doesn't having req.session.user, I am not sure where I made a mistake.

Thanks in advance.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

//******SESSION Handle *//
app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized:false,
    resave:true,
    name:"app.sid",
    secret: 'hello',
    cookie: { 
        secure: false,
        path:"/",
        maxAge  : 60000,
    },
}));

var Router = express.Router();
const cPool = require('../config/connectionPool');
const Tasks = require('./tasks');

//Login
Router.post('/login', function(req,res){
    Tasks.signIn(req, res, (err,rows)=>{
        if(err) return res.status(400).send({error:err.code,         message:err.sqlMessage});
        if(rows.length <= 0) return res.status(400).send({message:"Invalid Credentials"});
    var token = jwt.sign({ id: rows[0].user_id }, 'heydonttrustme', { 
          expiresIn : 60*60
    });
        req.session.user = rows[0].user_id;
        res.status(200).send({message:"Successfully Loggedin"});
    });
});


app.get('/', isLoggeIn, (req, res) =>{
  console.log('----', req.session);
})

const isLoggeIn = (req, res) => {
    if(!req.session.user) {res.status(401).send({message: "Not authorized"}) }
    else true
}
```

Comment: Can you log and check the value of `rows[0].user_id` in login handler?

Comment: to getting the logged user id from the database. its coming i checked it.

Comment: Are you calling APIs from a different domain on which API is hosted?

Comment: No in same domain

Comment: From domain I mean - Is your browser host from where you are calling API and your API server host are same or different?

Comment: Both are same domain, but I am using express-session via express.Router()